# Contacting a previous employee of the company

Tags: communication

A previous coworker who was with the company I work at left before I joined. No contact information was left. The work papers retained are inadequate in guiding me in the work I am doing. Obtaining this documentation will influence the degree of testing and the procedures I use going forward.

My intent is obtaining an understanding of their judgement in executing the work that was done and the conclusion reached.

I have discussed with my manager but he is unable to help me as this employee left about 6 months ago, and details are vague.

**How can I contact a previous employee of the company in such a circumstance?**

Comment: I would recommend not doing it. You must try to understand from whatever is available. Inform your manager. That would be unprofessional to contact someone who did something previously.

Comment: Why do you think the previous employee will have *any motivation whatsoever* to fix your problems? They've left the company.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about tracking someone down after you lost contact and as such is not specific to the Workplace.

Comment: No, it's specific to the workplace, just a very very unwise thing to do

Comment: @Lilienthal the question is also one of professionality and appropriateness in a workplace situation.

Comment: While I expect most answers (including my own) would respond to the question "how do I do this?" with "don't do that!", I think this is an absolutely appropriate question for The Workplace, and have voted to re-open.

Comment: @Anthony - when you say you discussed it with your manager, do you mean you discussed the problem you were having (and he was unable to help) or that you specifically discussed the prospect of contacting the former employee? If the latter - did he offer any suggestion that this was a good or bad idea? Or just say that he couldn't help with their contact details?

Comment: @HorusKol Well, that's only because what the OP is asking is a very unprofessional and misguided thing to attempt. The actual question isn't being answered below, mainly because the question is problematic so I don't think this should be reopened.

Answer (score 7):

> How can I contact a previous employee of the company in such a circumstance?

You don't, you talk to your manager and he/she organises it if they deem it necessary and/or possible.

Comment: That's your manager's job. Deciding whether contacting them is necessary, and contacting them. Obviously I would have no intention and no reason to help a company that I left 6 months ago. Not without compensation, and with compensation my current company would be quite unhappy.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, having to partially reverse-engineer a previous employee's work is not uncommon. It's always annoying. But it's a skill you're going to have to develop sooner or later.

Use the resources available to you: Who else in the team has worked in that area, or in something close enough that they could help you figure it out?

Answer (score 3):

Let your HR departement manage that.

Unless your former colleague has completely changed the field he will now be working for a  competitor and might not even be allowed to help you (and when in doubt HR is better prepared to handel legalities that might have to be dealt with).

Even if he wants to help you cannot expect him to work for free. You are probably not authorised to offer him payment, so again, let HR handle this.

Or even better, don't do this at all. It is unlikely that after 6 months he remembers enough details to be of much help, and nobody I know of likes to be stalked by their former workplace.

Answer (score 2):

Contact your HR.

They should have the basics information about how to contact this coworker.
If it is not possible, try linkedin.

You should understand that he does not have any incentive to help you apart from keeping good relationships with a former company. Ask the minimum possible.

Comment: Also, HR might tell you that you should not be doing this.